# How to change the font size for text input in Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, components, flash-cs6

I am having trouble changing the font size for the flash component, text input.
This text input component is already ready made where you can find it in components. 
So i just drag and drop it onto the stage. However, the font size is too small. And I can't change it. Or do I need to change it through coding in AS3? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that I was supposed to do that until now. I will do that from now onwards :) Thanks for reminding!

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for the information :) Yes, your answer did help me. It works like magic! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the text style for all instances of TextInput from one place, so whenever you drag a new TextInput component from Components panel and drop it on the stage, it will use your custom text style by default:

```
import fl.managers.StyleManager;
import fl.controls.TextInput;

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.size = 20;
StyleManager.setComponentStyle(TextInput, "textFormat", tf);
```

Furthermore, you can set the text style of all components (not just TextInput) from one place if you like to make all of them with the same style; this will give a better look especially if you have also changed the font family:

```
import fl.managers.StyleManager;
import fl.controls.TextInput;

var mainTF:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
mainTF.font = "Arial Black";
mainTF.color = 0xFF0000; 
mainTF.size = 20;
StyleManager.setStyle("textFormat", mainTF);
```

Please tell me if you need further help.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `TextInput`' style this way:

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.size = 18; // your value here
instanceName.setStyle("textFormat", format);
```

Read more about `TextFormat`: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html).